# while running python program getting IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1 in line 20 df3=df3[df3.columns[3]]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style

ds1 = pd.read_csv("latency.csv")
df1 = pd.DataFrame(ds1)
df1 = df1[df1.columns[1]]
latency_list = []
for latency in df1:
    latency_list.append(latency)
s = pd.DataFrame(ds1)
s = s[s.columns[6]]
stamp_list = []
for stamp in s:
    stamp_list.append(s)
ds2 = pd.read_csv("PacketLoss.csv")
packet_loss = (ds2["Count"][0]) - (ds2['Count'][4])

ds3 = pd.read_csv("RTP Packet Data.csv")
df3 = pd.DataFrame(ds3)
df3 = df3[df3.columns[3]]

average_jitter = df3.mean()

codec_delay = 10
for i in latency_list:
    effective_latency = i + 2 * average_jitter + codec_delay
    if effective_latency < 160:

        r = 93.2 - (effective_latency / 40)
    else:
        r = 93.2 - ((effective_latency - 120) / 10)
    r = r - 2.5 * packet_loss
    if r < 0:
        mos = 1.0
    else:

        mos = 1 + 0.035 * r + 0.000007 * r * (r - 60) * (100 - r)

style.use('fivethirtyeight')
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)


def animate(i):
    xs = []
    ys = []
    for j in stamp_list:
        xs.append(float(j))
    ys.append(float(mos))
    ax1.clear()
    ax1.plot(xs, ys)


ticks = [4.4, 4, 3, 2, 1]

labels = ["Best", "High", "Medium", "Low", "Poor"]
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)
plt.yticks(ticks, labels)
plt.xlabel("Timestamp")
plt.ylabel("Mean Openion Score")
plt.title("MOS VS TIME")
plt.show()
```

Comment: when i try to run getting below errorFile  line 20, in <module>
    df3=df3[df3.columns[3]]

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3930, in __getitem__
    return getitem(key)

IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1

Answer (score 0):

First off, let's do this;

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("latency.csv")
```

you don't need to do this (redundant);

```
ds1 = pd.read_csv("latency.csv")
df1 = pd.DataFrame(ds1)
```

I see what you are doing here. Indexing the column from the list of df3.columns. But it looks as though it must not exist.

```
df3 = df3[df3.columns[3]]
```

Remember that indexing starts at 0, then moves up.
It's better to do this instead;

```
df3 = df3['column name'] # select the values in this specific column
```

It's much better to use the column name over the indexing name. At least in my experience.

And actually you would be better to make some other variable store the column. Like;

```
average_jitter = df3['column name'].mean()
```

This way you don't overwrite the DataFrame and can continue to reference it.

You can also do something like this to enumerate over your DataFrame, I'm starting to value it a lot more over moving through a list or a range.

```
for c,r in df1.iterrows():
    latency_list.append(r['latency'])
# or whatever the column name is that has latency stored in it
```